# 初期化メソッドでインスタンスの区別をする方法

Tags: python

一番年齢が若い人の名前を出力したいです。（同じ年齢の場合、p1を出力）

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name 
        self.age=age

    def print_younger_person_name(p1,p2):
        return p1.name if p2.age>=p1.age else p2.name

    
a=Person("太郎",34)
b=Person("七子",32)

print(print_younger_person_name(a,b))
```

Comment: この度はお二方ご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問のタイトルと本文の説明は関連していません。
本文に書かれた内容を行うために「初期化メソッドでインスタンスの区別をする」必要はありません。

「???の部分に if や else で分岐させます。`pa.age > pb.age` みたいな感じにしたい」時には、`def print_young(p):`の引数を2つ用意します。

```
def print_young(pa, pb):
    younger = pb if pa.age > pb.age else pa
    return younger.name
```

あるいは：

```
def print_young(pa, pb):
    return pb.name if pa.age > pb.age else pa.name
```

呼び出す際は引数を2つ指定します。

```
a=People("小田太郎",34)
b=People("山田奈子",32)

print(print_young(a, b))
```

---

コメント対応：

更新した質問記事では、`print_younger_person_name()`が`Person`クラスのメソッドになっているのでエラーが発生しています。
以下のようにインデントを解除して`Person`クラスのメソッドではなくせば、呼び方は変わりません。

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name 
        self.age=age

def print_younger_person_name(p1,p2):
    return p1.name if p2.age>=p1.age else p2.name
```

これを`Person`クラスのメソッドに変更したい時は以下のようにして、呼び方も変える必要があります。

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name 
        self.age=age
    
    def print_younger_person_name(self,param):
        return self.name if param.age>=self.age else param.name

a=Person("太郎",34)
b=Person("七子",32)

print(a.print_younger_person_name(b))
# あるいは
print(b.print_younger_person_name(a))
```

Comment: 少々メソッド名に変更を加えました。これでやると、'NameError: name 'print_younger_person_name' is not defined' と出てしまいます。　おかしなところがあれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: それはメソッドの名前を変えただけでは無く、単独の定義からPersonクラスのインスタンスメソッドに変えたからですね。Personクラスに属さないメソッドに戻せば(インデントを解除すれば)エラーにはならないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

二人だけの比較であればメソッドや関数を作成しなくてもよいでしょう。

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name 
        self.age=age

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=Person("太郎",34)
    b=Person("七子",32)

    print([a, b][a.age > b.age].name)
```

> 一番年齢が若い人

人数が不定の場合は以下の様にしてもよいかと思います。
※ dataclass を使用しているため、実行には Python 3.7 以降が必要

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

def youngest_person_name(*persons: Person) -> Optional[str]:
    if not persons: return None
    if len(persons) == 1: return persons[0].name
    return sorted(persons, key=lambda x: x.age)[0].name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Person('小田太郎', 34)
    b = Person('山田奈子', 32)
    c = Person(name='Joel Spolsky', age=57)

    name = youngest_person_name(a, b, c)
    print(name)
```